# Is there a way to provide JSON data instead of JSON URL to HighCharts Charting API?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am using HighCharts library to generate line charts. Right now the HighCharts method take a API URL and makes the call to fetch the data.

```
function draw_chart(data_url, symbol, div_id) {
    console.log("Fetching aggregates from: " + data_url)
    Highcharts.getJSON(data_url, function (data) {
        // Create the chart
        Highcharts.stockChart(div_id, {
            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },
    
            title: {
                text: `${symbol} Stock Price`
            },
    
            series: [{
                name: symbol,
                data: data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    });
```

Is there a way for me to make the API and then pass the data to HighCharts?

The reason for this is that I want to pass some custom headers to the API that I am not able to do when HighCharts is making the call.

Thank You

Comment: It doesn't look like the `getJSON` method is a pre-requisite for using `stockChart` - it's just recommended. Have you tried creating the chart without using it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the `Highcharts.getJSON` method. You can provide JSON from any source, for example:

```
fetch('https://api.npoint.io/a6c906a1130a9b208ff7')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => createChart(data));


const createChart = (data) => {
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        series: [{
            data
        }]
    });
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/krvw8ujm/